# Cannot trigger pubsub function in google cloud functions emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are trying to create a development environment before publishing our firebase functions.

We have successfully installed and started a local emulator, can access our firestore database, can call the HTTPS endpoints and everything. Starting `firebase emulators:start` shows:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./testdata
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore, hosting, pubsub
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, database
⚠  Your requested "node" version "12" doesn't match your global version "14"
i  firestore: Importing data from /home/forest/projects/icell/i_cell_parking_manager/firebase/testdata/firestore_export/firestore_export.overall_export_metadata
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  pubsub: Pub/Sub Emulator logging to pubsub-debug.log
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: webserver
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "..../firebase/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions[createParkingReservationsForNextWeek]: pubsub function initialized.
✔  functions[reserveSpaceForUser]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/i-cell-parking-manager-backend/us-central1/reserveSpaceForUser).

┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! View status and logs at localhost:4000 │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI      │
├───────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ localhost:4000/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ localhost:8080 │ localhost:4000/firestore │
├───────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting   │ localhost:5000 │ n/a                      │
├───────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ Pub/Sub   │ localhost:8085 │ n/a                      │
└───────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
  Other reserved ports: 4400, 4500
```

We have a function called `createParkingReservationsForNextWeek` which is a timed single pubsub, we want to trigger it without needing to wait for the scheduler.

```
 */
exports.createParkingReservationsForNextWeek = functions.pubsub
    .schedule(WEEKLY_NOTIFICATION_SCHEDULE)
    .timeZone(TIMEZONE_EUROPE_BUDAPEST)
....
```

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#web we can do that by navigation to this URL in a browser: `http://localhost:5001/i-cell-parking-manager-backend/us-central1/createParkingReservationsForNextWeek`

But upon that we get this error (which can be seen in the emulator logs as well):

```
 functions: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:580:28
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:12)
    at processBackground (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:577:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:673:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

In the logs (http://localhost:4000/logs):

```
 
14:50:31
I
function[createParkingReservationsForNextWeek]
Beginning execution of "createParkingReservationsForNextWeek"
14:50:31
W
function[createParkingReservationsForNextWeek]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:580:28
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:12)
    at processBackground (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:577:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:673:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
14:50:31
W
function[createParkingReservationsForNextWeek]
Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

Cloud-firestore-emulator version is `v1.11.9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a pub/sub function locally by calling it by name in the firebase shell:

Terminal 1: `firebase emulators:start`

Terminal 2: `firebase functions:shell` then `createParkingReservationsForNextWeek()`

If you need to include data on invocation (likely the cause of your error above), you can do so as well:

```
// invokes a function with the JSON message { hello: 'world' } and attributes { foo: 'bar' }
myPubsubFunction({data: new Buffer('{"hello":"world"}'), attributes: {foo: 'bar'}})
```

See the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#invoke_pubsub_functions) for more details.

Comment: It escaped our attention that we could use the shell to trigger these. The documentation you linked is exactly what I needed.